# Python Writing Multiple Unequal Lists to Excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have mutiple lists

```
ANNA=(1, 2, 3, 4)
MAE=(1,2)
CEL=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

I want to write them in an excel or csv file format which looks like this:

[image]

When I used csv writer, i need to use `writerow` with additonal `'` so that the values will not be truncated in excel. It's fine, but still the other column is not appearing.

I use python3.x so izip does not work I guess coz I've tried it. 
I tried `pandas` and `DataFrame` but the columns need to be of equal lengths and my data is big and i do not know how to place `NaN` to my missing values. Besides, I wonder if there is a way instead of replacing `NaN` to equalize my columns it does not look good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest


ANNA = (1, 2, 3, 4)
MAE = (1, 2)
CEL = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["ANNA", "MAE", "CEL"])
    for row in zip_longest(ANNA, MAE, CEL):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Reference:

- zip_longest: https://pymotw.com/3/itertools/index.html#merging-and-splitting-iterators

Comment: This looks great but the output was truncated for example I have a value of 10454E+15 instead of displaying the actual number and the end digit was rounded off i think. When I added writer.writerow(" ' "+row) error shown was: TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in python 3:

```
>>> x = zip_longest(ANNA, MAE, CEL)
>>> [k for k in x]
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, None, 3), (4, None, 4), (None, None, 5), (None, None, 6), (None, None, 7)]
```